# I am using translation in my android app. Is there any way to force use english string using the getString method?

Tags: android, translation

I am using translation in my android app. Is there any way to force use english string using the getString method?? There are certain strings which I wish to use only in english but they are now translated.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the translation and put this strings in the strings.xml under the /values folder, to be used as a default fore every language.

Also, you could force a change in the Locale and modify it to use english as a language, but it's not really clean.